# I installed PHP and Apache successfully, then when I installed MySQL I encountered frustrating problems

Tags: mysql

I have looked at lots of forms and threads on this site.
First I installed MySQL using msi installer.

```
Configuration settings:
- detailed configuration
- developer machine
- multifunctional database
- initial path
- decision support
- enable tcp/icp networking, port 3306, add firewall exception for this port.
- enable strict mode
- best support for multilangualism
- install as windows service, include bin directory
- entered root password.
```

Then when I clicked execute it freezes after writing the configuration file.
- I closed that window.

Then when I opened MySQL Command Line Client and typed in the root password i get this..

> ERROR 2003: Can't connect to to MySQL server (10060)

I then opened up command prompt and typed.

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld --install
```

got message:

```
Install/remove of this service denied.
```

I ran the initial configuration as administrator and I have checked that port 3306 is open.

Hope this is detailed enough.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggesting uninstalling them all and reinstalling them with a package such as LAMP (for linux) or XAMPP (for windows). Much easier to install and set up, tutorials everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Can you get to the MySQL server instance config wizard in start menu

Is the MySQL service running?

whats the conf file look like?

Comment: no i can't get to the service instance config in start, only the command line client. No it says STOPPED.

Comment: i uninstalled the msi installer. installed it manually and now when i run mysqld in command prompt it says..  [ERROR] Can't find messagefile 'C:\mysql\share\errmsg.sys'

Comment: is there some code in that last bit? its just blank after "it says..."

Comment: did you get my edit? sorry i submitted the last comment by accident

Comment: what version windows and mysql are you trying to run?

Comment: windows 7, mysql 5.5      I have it so now mysql.exe will run. I got the last error message because i was pointing at the wrong basedir in my.ini

Comment: sorry this is late... i can access mysql but i cant start it as a windows service. When i exit mysql and type mysqld --install.. it says install.remove access denied

Comment: Kinda a shot in the dark here - have you tried disabling UAC in the control panel then going to the services and trying to start it manually - or try running the mysqld --install cmd from the admin cmd prompt?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. MySQL has been an nightmare for me. I ran command prompt as administrator and it worked. Now when i start the service it says MySQL starting so i think it is running okay. Again, thanks.

Comment: MySQL tends to be a nightmare for Windows in general - Unless you use WAMP....But glad i could help

Comment: One more thing if you don't mind. In services instead of saying 'started' it says 'starting'. does that matter?

Comment: yes - it needs to be running - i assume youve restarted? Can you pull your error log and put it in a pastebin.com file?

Comment: yes MySQL is eventually working! Thanks so much. Now i will have to sit for hours trying to install phpmyadmin

Comment: Hey - scroll to the bottom of this page - itll scoot you thru phpMyAdmin setup http://connectwww.com/how-to-install-and-configure-apachephpmysql-and-phpmyadmin-on-windows/457/